# Writing a project journal for creative coding University module, want to write it in JS/C#

Tags: javascript, c#, journal

I study Music Technology at university, and am doing a module on Sound for Interactive Media. The aim of the module is to create an app (Unity3D) or webapp (JS) that contains sound in some way or form.

One of the assessment criteria is to keep a project journal. I've previously done this by writing a text document with date headers and just explaining each thought process I had at each stage. However for this module I feel like partially writing the journal in JS/C# depending on which route I choose for my app.

I'm stuck because its seeming like most of this journal is going to be

/* */

commented out like above. Does anyone here have experience of writing a journal in a programming language? Maybe I could make it slightly more complex and make is so that each journal entry appears with a click? I quite like the idea of it just being a txt file though, because my module tutors are music live coders, so I feel like they'd find awful jokes in the // comments funny

Thanks in advance

[What I have so far...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2hzE.png)

Comment: Please dont provide code as a picture, include it directly in your question.

Comment: You could use regular expressions to the content of your .cs or .js files and extract the comments (your journal). Anyway, I wonder how you will differenciate your journal from real code comments.